# How to startForeground() service in smali code without showing notification by Android Reversing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smali, reversing

I'm attempting to hide the Foreground notification without showing notification in android apk and the start foreground service working fine with this smali code:

```
invoke-virtual {p0, v1, v0}, LX/XX/XXX/XXXX;->startForeground(ILandroid/app/Notification;)V
```

And the foreground java code which i reversed from apk looks like this:

```
if ((Notification v0 = a.f(this.getApplicationContext()))) {    
      this.startForeground(2004, v0);
   }
```

**In the onCreate method!**

As a begginer What i've tried is deleting the foreground service from smali code hence code removal results in non persistent service so the app doesn't works on the background..

What are some possible things that i can do in order to achieve persistency with notification service but without showing the notification?

Tricky ways can also work like showing transparent/hidden notification etc!